# Access array element in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, arrayref

Dumper(@releases) has the following

```
$VAR1 = '\projects\proj mypac : test / 04.00.00; 0';
```

When I do print ( $releases[0]) it gives

```
\projects\proj mypac : test / 04.00.00; 0
```

I want individual elements like

```
$releases[0] = \projects\proj;
$releases[1] = mypac;
$releases[2] = mypac;
$releases[3] = 04.00.00;
$releases[4]  = 0;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) your string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '\projects\proj mypac : test / 04.00.00; 0';

my @fields = split m{\s*[:/;]?\s+}, $string;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@fields;
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '\\projects\\proj',
          'mypac',
          'test',
          '04.00.00',
          '0'
        ];
```

Comment: @releases is an array so I am afraid I couldn't use the solution

Comment: Yes, `@releases` is a 1 element array.  Therefore just access the scalar using `$releases[0]`.  Perhaps read: [Modern Perl Book - The Perl Language](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/03-perl-language.html)

Comment: I have used first element of array in the place of $string and got it working :-) Thank you :)